# Is it possible to enforce an authentication type at a user/role level?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have some users/roles that use basic username/password auth and some that use key pair auth.

I'm just wondering if it is possible to only allow a single auth type at a user/role level? I.e. the user can login using key pair but not with username/password etc?

Comment: One possible way would be to create an alias for snowsql command (if that's what users use) and push to users profile and set in the path. 
This will ensure all the users gets to use the same specific authenticator type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may alter the user to set the password to ''. This disables the users to use user/password authentication.

they would still be able to use key pair authentication

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify, set the user password to a single double quote, is that correct? However I assume this approach would not stop a user, that has valid basic auth, from using key pair?

Comment: Alter user <UserName> set password =' ';

Yes, this may not stop user for using the Keypair